# imagecreatetruecolor contains which values?

Tags: php, image, canvas, png, var-dump

Code is pretty much self explanatory...

I was wonder what $canvas is carry after setting `imagecreatetruecolor(360,240)`

```
$canvas=imagecreatetruecolor(360,240);

var_dump($canvas);
```

Output :

```
resource(2) of type (gd)
```

How can I really get what's going on inside `$canvas` ?

Comment: Great but how come php knows how to deal that black image that stored inside $canvas in that example ? Must be a way to echo what's REALLY going on inside $canvas...

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to obtain an array of bytes representing your image in bitmap format? Or what? Whatever; the internal representation of `$canvas` is abstracted away from you and you should not care about it. Let the library do its job and use its documented functions.